# Set an UIImage to an Imageview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Just started coding and i am running in to the following problem:

I have set up the following struct:

```
struct Question {
var Question: String!
var Answers: [String]!
var Answer : Int!
var Image :  UIImage!
```

}

Connected the UIImageView as: @IBOutlet var Qimage: UIImageView!

I tried to fill the struct, and all the data is displayed correctly except the image? Example:

```
Questions = [Question(Question: "test?", Answers: ["1","2","3","4"], Answer: 2, Image: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "test"))
```

At last i am trying to fill the struct with a function and used:

`Qimage.image = Questions[Qnumber].Image`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Please avoid too many images and also use formatting.

Comment: What do you mean exactly, because it could become more than 150 images?

Comment: You could have provided a snippet of your code that you encounter problem.

Comment: Aah ok sorry, will keep that in mind for the future!

Comment: Please edit your question to INCLUDE the relevant code. Link only questions become useless when the links to the external content become invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `UIImage(named: "Test")`.. instead of `UIImage(contentsOfFile: "Test")`